# Align elements in horizontally in angular schema form

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-schema-form

I have following code :

```
var modelForm=[
  {
    type: 'fieldset',
    title: 'Component',
    items: [
      {
        type: 'tabs',
        tabs: [
          {
            title: 'Product',
            items: [
              'productName',
              'releaseVersion',
              'distroName',
              'stackCategory',
.....
.....
{ type: 'submit', title: 'Update', condition: 'model.id && ! confirmDelete' },
  { type: 'submit', title: 'Create', condition: '!model.id && !confirmDelete' },
  { type: 'button', title: 'Cancel', onClick: 'cancel()', condition: '!confirmDelete' },
  { type: 'button', title: 'Delete', onClick: 'confirmDelete=true' , condition: 'model.id && ! confirmDelete'},
  { type: 'help', helpvalue: '<h1 class=\'\'>Are you sure you want to delete?<h1>', condition: 'confirmDelete' },
  { type: 'button', title: 'Don\'t delete', onClick: 'confirmDelete=false',condition: 'confirmDelete' },
  { type: 'button', title: 'Confirm delete', onClick: 'deleteModel()' , condition: 'confirmDelete'}
```

Because of using fieldset, all the elements are coming vertically. I want the buttons - Create, Cancel, and Delete described in then end to be in one line.

how can I achieve this?

Comment: post a fiddle or plnkr of the current result which you are getting now.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this for just two buttons ("cancel", "save") by adding the following bootstrap less style:

```
.schema-form-submit {
  display: inline;
}

.schema-form-submit input {
  .pull-right;
}
```